# Get Request Scheme in Traefik access-log

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

Is it possible to have request scheme (http or https) in Traefik access-log? (not BackendURL.Scheme)

Answer (score 0):

It has been added in newer traefik versions:

https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/6255